# Sveltekit - is there a way to run code before onMount

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I want to protect my login page from being loaded if the user is already logged in.

I tried doing the following:

```
<script>
onMount(() => {
        // if the user is already logged in do not display this page, redirect the user
        // to any other page.
        if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
            goto("/pos");
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
but doesn't work, because according to the documentation, `onMount` runs right after the component is mounted so the form is always visible for a few milliseconds before being redirected to `/pos`. Is there a way to run code before the component mounts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. add a `+page.server.ts`/`js` file and intercept the loading of the page:

```js
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load = async ({ cookies }) => {
    if (cookies.get('auth') == '...')
        throw redirect(302, '/');
}
```

See [routing docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

There also is a [`beforeNavigate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-beforenavigate) hook that can prevent navigations on the client. Though if the user is logged in, you probably should no longer have any visible links to the login page anyway.

Comment: thanks, let me try that. There are currently no visible links to visit login page, but it can be accessed using the URL, so that's what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: so, if I want to achieve the same but on client side shall I use `+page.js`?

Comment: @MrCujo: Not quite. You cannot access the cookies on the client, you probably would want to put that `beforeNavigate` hook a high level `+layout.svelte` and prevent any navigation to the login page from occurring in the first place.

Comment: (Also, the `load` function in `+page.js` runs on both client *and* server because of SSR.)

Comment: so I've added the `beforeNavigate` hook to `+layout.svelte`, in there I'm checking the requested page via `$page.url.pathname=='/login'` and also whether the user is logged in via a helper function I had written `isUserLoggedIn()`, if so redirect, and although it works, it works exactly as the previous solution i had: the login page is loaded and then quickly redirected to a different one

Comment: See the docs, you should be able to completely prevent navigation calling `cancel()` on the event argument.

Comment: You can also use the browser boolean from the environment, as the code won't run on the server, but on the client, like this  (assuming you imported browser from "$app/environment") `if (browser) {goto("/pos")};` You might want to consider the user's logged in state in a store, and update it when the user logs in and out, and retrieve the values from the cookie to set a default on page load.